# How would I format a report layout in excel into a Python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I receive data in multiple formatted files - most of which are fairly straightforward as they are either csv or tabular excel. My challenge is when I receive an excel file formatted to look like a report - and I need to get that into a dataframe.

I get a LOT of these files daily so ideally my routine - which works for the most part - to take the file and get it formatted automatically.

Any help would be awesome.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Asking about recommendations for software libraries is off-topic here. However, if you have a specific question about your code, it might be on-topic. Also, please try to search for a solution first. There are already MANY questions and answers about reading Excel files using Python. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can export as csv and import using pandas' `read_csv()` method.
I assume the fist 4 rows (40050 - Income statement, ..., 3000 - Cash and cash eq.) are not needed as data. If they are alway consistent, you can pass `header=x` where `x` is the number of not used lines as parameter. Doing so will skip them. After that you can do pretty much anything.

Comment: I woudl actually need to replicate the 3000 | Cash Equivalents in the empty fields below, until I bump into one with a new label e.g. 3010 | Petty Cash (as a bad example) and then fill the empty fields below and so on.